# Gitlab CI copy file with variables

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a `django` repository in `gitlab` service. And I use gitlab CI runner in my VDS. I want a copy some file during deploy process, for example `local_settings.py` and fill variables only on deploy, for example like this:

```
# $CI_PROJECT_NAME/$CI_PROJECT_NAME/deploy_templates/local_settings.py.tpl
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'dbname',
        'USERNAME': '$DB_USERNAME',
        'PASSWORD': '$DB_PASSWORD',
    },
}

# .gitlab-ci.yml
configure_project:
    script:
        - git clone $CI_BUILD_REPO
        - cp $CI_PROJECT_NAME/$CI_PROJECT_NAME/deploy_templates/local_settings.py.tpl $CI_PROJECT_NAME/$CI_PROJECT_NAME/local_settings.py
```

In my project I define `DB_USERNAME` and `DB_PASSWORD` secure variables. How I can to get file with values? I need something like `template` directive from `ansible`

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using `envsubst` command. In your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file you can do the following:

```yaml
configure_project:
    script:
        - git clone $CI_BUILD_REPO
        - envsubst < "$CI_PROJECT_NAME/$CI_PROJECT_NAME/deploy_templates/local_settings.py.tpl" > "local_settings.py.tpl.exported"
        - cp local_settings.py.tpl.exported $CI_PROJECT_NAME/$CI_PROJECT_NAME/local_settings.py
```

[`envsubst`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/envsubst-Invocation.html) will substitute the values of environment variables and the output can be redirected to another file called `local_settings.py.tpl.exported` which you can copy.